# Opening a java JAR file from python

Tags: python, jar

I am trying to open a JAR file from python and running into problems. I am using..

```
import os
os.system(r"X:\file.jar")
```

it appears to open the window then it shuts right away, I know I am missing a simple command but not sure what it is, thanks for the help

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you want to execute code from .jar, or open it?

If open, then `.jar` file is the same format as `.zip` files and you can use `zipfile` module to manipulate it. Example:

```
def show_jar_classes(jar_file):
    """prints out .class files from jar_file"""
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(jar_file, 'r')
    try:
        lst = zf.infolist()
        for zi in lst:
            fn = zi.filename
            if fn.endswith('.class'):
                print(fn)
    finally:
        zf.close()
```

If you want to execute it then I prefer creating simple batch/shell script which execute `java` with some parameters like `-Xmx` and with environment settings required by application.

Comment: Still can't get this to appear open and nothin

Comment: Adam, you must answer you very important question: what I want to do with this `.jar` file? Execute? Show content? Add some new file? This answer shows how to open .jar and show its content, other answer shows you how to execute such file. Those two answers shows the most useful operations for .jar.

Answer (score 0):

For the previous question, Executing it is easy.

`import os
os.system('start X:\file.jar')`