# Java and Python

Tags: java, python

I am trying to open a java link I have saved on my folder on my desktop. I can't get it to find the file. The java address is x:\green\Adam\FILEJAR.jar. This is an executable JAR file I want to open it and have it on my desktop, just open it and have it run as normal for the Java link. Want Python just to open it.

```
import subprocess
run="x:\green\Adam\FILEJAR.jar"
proc=subprocess.Popen(run)
```

I get this....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python32/test3", line 3, in <module>
proc=subprocess.Popen(run)
File "C:\Python32\lib\subprocess.py", line 741, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Python32\lib\subprocess.py", line 960, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

What am I doing wrong, why can't it find the file?

Comment: This has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007274/python-open-a-jar-shortcut

Comment: The only thing to add here is what @larsmans mentioned in his answer: prefix the path string with `r` to preserve the forward slashes: `run=r"x:\green\Adam\FILEJAR.jar"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening a java JAR file from python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005300/opening-a-java-jar-file-from-python)

Answer (score 1):

The jar file itself is nothing but an archive with byte-compiled java code. 
To execute it properly, try:

```
import subprocess
run = r"java -jar x:\green\Adam\FILEJAR.jar"
proc = subprocess.Popen(run)
```

Comment: Won't work. Eiter add a `, shell=True` to the `Popen()` call, or set `run = ['java', '-jar', r'x:\reen\Adam\FILEJAR.jar']`.

Comment: I run it with no errors but it isn't visible, tried proc.Visible =True, nothing??? can I make it visible?

Comment: Still can't get the java script to become a visible screen kinda stuck on it