# Python Using Jar File

Tags: python, jar, process

I'm trying to use a jar file in python using the library `os`.

I succeeded to run the jar file without a problem using the function `os.system()`

my command was like this:

```
cmd = "java -jar ./scripts/my_jar/users.jar"
os.system(cmd)
```

I would like to ask:

1. do I need to kill the process (the jar file)?
2. or python will kill the jar file automatically after the termination of the python file??

Comment: `os.system` will return only when the java process is ended/killed. It's unclear what you're meaning by "killing the jar file", though

Comment: Would this help? [Opening a java JAR file from python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8005300/13552470)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to kill the jar file independently of the python program, at least with os.system. After the python program is terminated (you stop the process forcefully) the jar file will also terminate. Note, however, that if you prematurely kill/stop the python file, the jar will be forced to terminate without returning an output.

2. python will kill the jar file automatically after the termination of the python file